# How do I resolve the OAuthException 100 Requires user session error when accessing Facebook?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-access-token

I created my app and sent a request to Facebook with the following parameters:

```
facebookClient.AppId = APP_ID;
facebookClient.AppSecret = APP_SECRET;
facebookClient.AccessToken = APP_ACCESS_TOKEN;
```

However, when I try to get page statuses, I get the error:

> OAuthException 100  Requires user session

What does this error mean?  How do I resolve it?

Using a Facebook C# SDK to get this error.

The user that created this app has the `manage_pages` permission on the page I want to get status updates from.

Answer (score 0):

To query for the "page statuses", you need to pass the `user_access_token`, not the `app_access_token`.

The user access token is obtained at the authorization step. For eg:

```
//authorization
session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("manage_pages");
string access_token = session.AccessToken;
string fb_id = session.FacebookId;
```